# Android elevation is not working with dark background color

Tags: android

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/dark_green"
        android:elevation="32dp"
        android:outlineProvider="background"/>
```

I tried to add a dropdown shadow with my code above, but if the background color is dark, I don't see the shadow. But if the color is white it works fine.

Please do not suggest `<layer-list>` or drawable. I need to use outline and elevation.

Comment: Are you sure, that there's no shadow? Sometimes it's hard to spot as the shadow is transparent black by default. The easiest way to make sure is to take a screenshot and check it in a bitmap editor.

Comment: Yeah i am sure. background of screen is white for see shadow

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the view inside cardview for shadow effect.

If you want to change the card background color, use:

```
app:cardBackgroundColor="@somecolor"
```

like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white">

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```